# Efficient Way to Debug Tkinter Programs

Tags: python, debugging, tkinter

I have been using tkinter to design my application. I usually use print statements to debug the program in the mainloop. My Question is that is there any efficient way of debugging the tkinter programs so that it can show the debug window from which I can inspect the values.

Comment: Massively depends on which IDE you are using and it's support for debugging functions.

Comment: I am using VS Code